# KafkaContainer - how to read kafka container port as property in Spring Boot after start() / how to configure Kafka port before starting

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, testcontainers

I am doing integration testing with `KafkaContainer`; after starting the container, the port is chosen randomly.

I can get the port by `container.getBootStrapServer()`, but what I need is to put the dynamic host+port in the properties (`application-itest.yml`, under `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`, because that is where Spring Kafka picks the value to configure my bean of `KafkaTemplate`).

Or, if I can set the port to be a static value while starting `KafkaContainer`, like `9999`, and set it in the yaml file, it also will work. I don't know how to do neither.(Do I need to inject another bean of `KafkaTemplate` after getting the value?)

How do I start KafkaContainer:

```
    public static final KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(
            DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3")
    );
    private AdminClient adminClient;

    ...

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        if (adminClient == null) {
            kafka.start();
            // here value is dynamic and is not accessible in Environment; not as `@AutoConfigureWiremock`, I have `wiremock.server` value set after)
            String bootStrapServer = kafka.getBootstrapServers();
            log.info("Kafka container created at: {}", bootStrapServer);
            adminClient = AdminClient.create(Map.of(
                    AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServer
            ));
            // create my topic
            log.info("Current topic: {}", topic);
            adminClient.createTopics(Set.of(
                    new NewTopic(topic, 4, (short) 1)
            ));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find no way to do it. At last I turn to `EmbeddedKafka` and populate the host+port with SpEL `"spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}"`. That works even with `@TestPropertySource(properties={xxx})`.

Basically in this post: https://blog.mimacom.com/testing-apache-kafka-with-spring-boot-junit5/

Remember that the property setting should be done at test level, because when you only want to use Kafka in some itest, adding the property to `application-itest.yml` will cause **all** itest classes to look for EmbeddedKafka in the classpath and panic when you don't add `@EmbeddedKafka` on them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [@DynamicPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/DynamicPropertySource.html):

> Method-level annotation for integration tests that need to add
> properties with dynamic values to the Environment's set of
> PropertySources. This annotation and its supporting infrastructure
> were originally designed to allow properties from Testcontainers based
> tests to be exposed easily to Spring integration tests. However, this
> feature may also be used with any form of external resource whose
> lifecycle is maintained outside the test's ApplicationContext.
>
> Methods annotated with @DynamicPropertySource must be static and must
> have a single DynamicPropertyRegistry argument which is used to add
> name-value pairs to the Environment's set of PropertySources. Values
> are dynamic and provided via a Supplier which is only invoked when the
> property is resolved.

In your test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;

@Testcontainers
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class XxxTest {

@Container
private static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse(KAFKA_IMAGE));

@DynamicPropertySource
static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", () -> { 
        return kafkaContainer.getHost() + ":" + kafkaContainer.getFirstMappedPort();
    });
    registry.add("spring.kafka.admin.properties.min-in-sync-replicas", () -> 1);
    registry.add("spring.kafka.admin.properties.number-of-replicas", () -> 1);     
}

@Test
@Order(1)
void kafkaContainerIsRunning()  { 
    waitForAssignment();
    
    assertThat(kafkaContainer.isRunning()).isTrue();
}

private void waitForAssignment() {
    kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()
        .forEach(container -> 
            ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, 1));
}
```

Comment: To use `@Container` import `org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container`

Comment: This works for me but I get an exception in the test. It seems that the dynamic property source is already checked before the container is up. Can this be avoided?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createSender' defined in Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started

Comment: Hi @ChristianSchneider, check [this](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2290),  might help.